# C++ Support from Firebase Realtime DB

Tags: c++, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does Firebase support C++ for Realtime Database? I can't seem to find any documentation about it. 
If there is, can you please point me out on the documentation? Please.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no C++ SDK for accessing the Firebase Realtime Database. There is a REST API that you can access from almost any language.

Comment: Thank you, @FrankvanPuffelen! I hope you'll support this in the future. :)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen we won't get the sync part in the REST API right - so is the preferred way for cross platform mobile dev using JNI or something?

Comment: You *can* use our [REST streaming API for the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-streaming) to get streaming, similar to listeners in the SDKs. But it'll definitely more involved.

Answer (score 1):

Since 2.0 version of Firebase C++ SDK it provides bindings for Realtime Database.
Also, in 2.1 version from (9 dec of 2016) Google adds the Firebase Storage bindings.

Answer (score 0):

It does support C++. 
This link has the guidelines for implementation of Firebase Realtime Database in C++:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/cpp/start

The Firebase Realtime Database Test Application (testapp) demonstrates Firebase Realtime Database operations with the Firebase Realtime Database C++ SDK. The application has no user interface and simply logs actions it's performing to the console. 
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-cpp/tree/master/database/testapp