# How can you integrate Firebase SDK into a C++ DLL?

Tags: c++, firebase-realtime-database, c++17

I already have a fully functional and working C++ DLL that simply saves data into a text file in my C drive and below is the working code that just that.

Working C++ DLL file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
using namespace std;

double saveNumToFile(double num, int filenum) {


    stringstream ss;
    ss << filenum;
    string str = ss.str();

    std::string firstdir = "C://";
    std::string lastdir = ".txt";
    std::string directory = firstdir + str + lastdir;

    ofstream myfile(directory);

    if (myfile.is_open())
    { 
        myfile << num;
        myfile.close();
    }
    return num;
}
```

The code above works. But now, instead of having the data saved into a text file and sits in my C drive, I want to use the Real-time Database that Firebase offers.

And while Firebase docs said they've officially support C++ from this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663653/c-support-from-firebase-realtime-db) and also in the [Firebase getting started page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/cpp/start), it only shows how to implement either using iOS or Android and nowhere I can find docs that specifically shows how to interface the SDK using plain C++.

I've made attempts to include a header file but it fails. Mainly because I am a novice C++ and that the steps mentioned in the guides do not show how to implement using plain C++ files to be compiled as DLL.

**I need guidance** on how to include the C++ SDK into my existing CPP file so that I can add additional code to call the relevant Firebase functions and hoping that when I compile the DLL using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition, I can get the DLL to work exactly as it does by saving the data not to a text file this time but in Firebase Real-time Database.

I am still a novice C++ user but I understand the fundamentals so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It appears that Firebase "supports C++" as in "supports C++ on Android". Furthermore, the best use of time for a "novice C++ user" would be to continue reading a good C++ book, and learning the language fundamentals such as classes, inheritance, polymorphism, templates, and the C++ library -- instead of attempting to interface with a fairly complicated third party library.

Comment: Firebase does not really provide desktop SDKs as it is primarily targeted at mobile and web applications and games. If you want to integrate a database into your application there's plenty of other choices though (such as e.g.: SQLite)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks. I've tried using firebase in web using plain javascript and its cool. I just thought I could also do it in C++ ;)

Comment: @UnholySheep Thanks. I can use MySQL and thats not a problem. But having this "ServerLess" thing that Firebase offers is a great option only if theres a way for it to work.